# Configuring Kernel on Buildroot to integrate RAUC

Tags: linux, buildroot

I am integrating RAUC with buildroot for the IMX8MM board. As mentioned in the documentation of RAUC, I have selected "rauc" package in the `linux-menuconfig` which automatically sets the dependencies. As the next involves configuring kernel, I bit confused about the settings to configure the kernel. We already have a minimal_config kernel for the target and it needs to be modified to integrate RAUC. In the documentation [RAUC documentation](https://rauc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#kernel-configuration) its mentioned to enable these below settings:

> In kernel Kconfig you have to enable the following options:
> CONFIG_MD=y,
> CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM=y,
> CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=y,
> CONFIG_DM_VERITY=y,
> CONFIG_SQUASHFS=y,
> CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA256=y

Can anyone please let me know how to enable these using `make linux-menuconfig` option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may want to try `make linux-xconfig` which gives you a GUI.

When you run `make linux-menuconfig`, you get a textual menu. It's quite difficult to find specific options by browsing through these menus, so there's a search function: type `/` (slash) and you get a search box. Type `CONFIG_MD` to find that symbol. Then you get a list of possible matches. Find the one you need. It should have a number before the menu entry:

```
Symbol: MD [=n]                                           
Type  : bool                                              
Defined at drivers/md/Kconfig:6                           
  Prompt: Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)  
  Depends on: BLOCK [=y]                                  
  Location:                                               
(1) -> Device Drivers                                     
Selects: SRCU [=n]
```

Type that number (i.e. `1`) and you will be brought directly to that option. There you can enable it.

If no number appears before it, it means that it's an option that can't be selected directly (i.e. not a user-visible option). I don't think that that's the case for any of the options mentioned.

Sometimes you don't get brought to the option you need, but to its containing menu instead. This happens when one of the dependencies of the option is not met - cfr. the `Depends on` line in the search results. You can search again for these dependencies to enable them as well.

After finishing, remember to save the result with `make linux-update-defconfig`.